# CoinFlipGame help.. Input True in a if statement

Tags: java, helper, game-maker

This is a game i am trying to make. You start off the game with $1500, and every time you want to play the game you must pay $100.( select 1 to play) (press 2 to read rule) (press 3 to see high scores) The game is a flipping coin game. When the game start there is $4 in the pot. When it's head the money in the pot doubles and you flip again. When it's tail , you obtain all the money in the pot. When you have less then $100 you are broke (game over). You return to the starting menu... And i wish to make it so that this game record your highest money (high score)
So this is what i got so far...

```
public class COINFLIP
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int tail = 0;//tail
int head = 0;//head
int x = 0;//tries
while (x < 1)
{
    int coin;//coin
    coin = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    x++;
    if (coin == 0) {
    headCount++; // int type
    wasHeads = true; // boolean type
    wasTails = false;
  } else {
    tailCount++;
    wasHeads = false; // boolean type
    wasTails = true;
 }
    int sm = 1500;//starting money
    int cm;//current money
    int pm = 4;//money in the pot
    cm = sm - 100 + pm;
}
if (wasHeads)
{
pm = pm * 2;
}
else if (wasTails)
{
System.out.println("Your money is: $" + cm);
}
if (cm < 100);
System.out.println("Sorry, but you are broke!!!");
}
}
```

errors:

```
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    headCount++; // int type
    ^
symbol:   variable headCount
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    wasHeads = true; // boolean type
    ^
symbol:   variable wasHeads
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    wasTails = false;
    ^
symbol:   variable wasTails
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
   tailCount++;
   ^
symbol:   variable tailCount
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    wasHeads = false; // boolean type
    ^
symbol:   variable wasHeads
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    wasTails = true;
    ^
symbol:   variable wasTails
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
if (wasHeads)
    ^
symbol:   variable wasHeads
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:27: error: illegal start of type
if (wasHeads)
   ^
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
pm = pm * 2;
^
symbol:   variable pm
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
pm = pm * 2;
     ^
symbol:   variable pm
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
else if (wasTails)
         ^
symbol:   variable wasTails
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:31: error: illegal start of type
else if (wasTails)
        ^
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Your money is: $" + cm);

                                        ^
symbol:   variable cm
location: class COINFLIP
C:\Users\Loyal Xie\Documents\COINFLIP.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
if (cm < 100);
    ^
symbol:   variable cm
location: class COINFLIP
14 errors
```

But there is a lot of errors, and my statement is still errored... i think the problem is with in      the if statement and i think i am still having trouble setting head = true and then use it in if statement....  Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: You have declared `head` as an `int`, so you cannot assign it to be `true`.

Comment: What are the rules to your game? This (`cm = sm - 100 + pm;`) is wrong. But I need to know the rules to fix it.

Comment: If you format your code then the errors will become much more obvious. Spend some time matching your {} brackets and correctly indenting each block.

Answer (score 0):

If you corrected your indentation you may notice that with

```
if (coin == 0)  
{
    headCount++; // int type   
}
    wasHeads = true; // boolean type
```

`wasHeads` is NOT in the if statement and will be executed 100% of the time.  The same is true for `wasTails = true;`

This means that later your testing for `if (wasHeads)` will always be executed.

Also, why have this in a `while` loop as it will only execute once.

**Edit**

Regarding your errors, you need to define variables before you can use them.

For example

```
headCount++;
```

Needs to be defined first as

```
int headCount = 0;
```

Comment: I see your solution and your suggestion ... The point of my code is to keep flipping the coin till you reach tail and you gain all the money in the pot ... And you have money you keep playing it . therefore the code must be able to run over and over .. So do you have any idea I could change my code in to something like that ...

Comment: replace `while (x < 1)` with `while (true)` and then when you `reach tail and you gain all the money in the pot` you will `break;`

Answer (score 0):

You assignments to your booleans aren't in their respective test cases (and you should really prefer the simple `else`). So something like,

```
if (coin == 0) {
  headCount++; // int type
  wasHeads = true; // boolean type
  wasTails = false;
} else {
  tailCount++;
  wasHeads = false; // boolean type
  wasTails = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `boolean wasHeads = false;` and `boolean wasTails = false;` somewhere. Please specify **what** error still occurs.